# Want to asser text present in Page Source Code or not

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

I want to assert certain text which are present in PageSource Code or not ,.

PageSource Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var rlSerial = '1057388';//Wanted to assert this text
    var rlAnid = 'I888pokerrussiaI';
    var rlFlag = '';
    var rlSearchTerm = '';
    var rlSearchEngine = '';
    var rlCurrency = '';
    var rlLang = 'en';
    var rlDl =  '';
    var rlCampaignId = '';
    var rlCountry = 'ind';
    var rlServerTime = '2015-08-10 10:37:53';
    var rlPid = '';
    var rlMkw = '';
    var MGbannerTag = '';
    var rlWtc  = '';
    var rlWtv  = '';

</script>
```

I had used following script , but it does not work

Webdriver Script:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-item-154']/a")).click();
String Tournament=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='text-31']/div/a/img")).getAttribute("outerHTML");
String VTournament=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tertiary']/div/div/div/p/a/img")).getAttribute("outerHTML");
Tournament.contains(Default_BannerName);
VTournament.contains(Default_VBannerName);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='text-31']/div/a/img")).click();
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
{
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
    boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains("var rlSerial = '1058358';");
    assertTrue(b);
}
```

Please Guide me Out

Comment: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  about commenting !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Only way you can read a variable is using javascript
//with <code>executeScript</code> method as shown bellow.
private void test(){
    String script = "return rlSerial;";
    String value = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
    System.out.println(value);
    //Use assert here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through all the `SCRIPT` tags and search for the desired text.

```
List<WebElement> scriptTags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("script"));
for (WebElement scriptTag : scriptTags)
{
    if (scriptTag.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("var rlSerial = '1058358';"))
    {
        // assertTrue()
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I just ran the code below and it worked fine for me... must be something on your end.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
String searchText = "document.body.style.visibility";
List<WebElement> scriptTags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("script"));
for (WebElement scriptTag : scriptTags)
{
    String text = scriptTag.getAttribute("outerHTML");
    if (text.contains(searchText))
    {
        System.out.println("Found it: " + text);
        // your assertTrue(...) goes here
        break;
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Found it: <script>if(google.j.b)document.body.style.visibility='hidden';</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I had implemented , but it does not assert any text , it just move on.

Comment: It works just fine for me. I tried it on google.com. Updated the answer to be more specific.